# How to search all <input> descendants of a DOM element and disable them

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, input

Let's say that I have a DOM object:

```
var a = document.getElementById('parent')
```

I want to search all `input` inside element `a`.

What should I do in jQuery?

I want to disable all input inside `a`, like syntax below:

```
$('#parent input').attr('disabled',true);
```

I tried

```
$(a).children('input').attr('disabled',true);
```

but gave no results.

Note: var `a` is an element I got from another function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(a).find('input').prop('disabled', true);
```

[`children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) just searches immediate children of the element while [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) searches all descendants.

**Update**: Also consider sinsedrix's remark on the [difference between `attr()` and `prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).

Comment: @SimonGate: Always the same with these simple jQuery questions...the answer rush ;)

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget `attr` is for HTML attributes and `prop` for DOM properties, try this:

```
$(a).find('input').attr('disabled','disabled');
```

or

```
$(a).find('input').prop('disabled',true);
```

Answer (score 1):

`$(a).find('input').attr('disabled',true)`

Answer (score 1):

```
$(a).find('input').attr('disabled',true);
```